# GoJS + Angular Links Do Not Avoid Nodes on Initial Load

Tags: angular, typescript, rendering, gojs

Hi I'm developing a workflow editor and renderer in Angular and GoJS, everything is pretty much working except that I'm running into an annoying bug where on initial page load the links do not properly avoid nodes, but the second you change the diagram or click on a router link and go back the link suddenly start behaving like they should. Doe anyone have any idea why this is happening ?

[Links not avoiding and properly avoiding nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3cHx.png)

Below is what I believe to be the relevant code, if anyone can help out that would be greatly appreciated

```
constructor(private templatesService: TemplatesService,
   private router: Router,
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private projectsService: ProjectsService) { this.initDiagram(); }

...

ngOnInit() {
   // Get data
   this.load();
   setTimeout(() => { this.load(); });

 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   // We have data page is loaded => show graph
   this._diagram.div = this._diagramRef.nativeElement;

   this.scaleDiagramDivToHeightOf(window, -50);
   if (this.route.data['value']['label'] === 'design' ||
       this.route.data['value']['label'] === 'design-proto') {
     this.initDiagramDesign();
     this.initPalette();
   }


   this._diagram.requestUpdate();


 }

 initDiagram() {
   this._diagram.commandHandler.defaultScale = 1.0;
   const that = this;
   this._diagram = new go.Diagram();
   this._diagram.initialContentAlignment = go.Spot.TopCenter;
   this._diagram.allowDrop = this.editMode;
   this._diagram.isReadOnly = !this.editMode;
   this._diagram.toolManager.draggingTool = new GuidedDraggingTool();
   this._diagram.undoManager.isEnabled = true;
   this._diagram.layout = $(go.TreeLayout, {
     angle: 90,
     nodeSpacing: 10,
     layerSpacing: 25,
     layerStyle: go.TreeLayout.LayerUniform, 
     arrangement: go.TreeLayout.ArrangementHorizontal
   });

   this._diagram.nodeTemplateMap.add(""...
   this._diagram.linkTemplate =
     $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
       {
         routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
         curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
         corner: 10, toShortLength: 4,
         relinkableFrom: true,
         relinkableTo: true,
         reshapable: true,
         resegmentable: true,
         // mouse-overs subtly highlight links:
         selectionAdorned: false,
       },
       // new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
       $(go.Shape,  // the highlight shape, normally transparent
         { isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 8, stroke: "transparent", name: "HIGHLIGHT" }),
       $(go.Shape,  // the link path shape
         { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 2 },
         new go.Binding("stroke", "isSelected", function (sel) { return sel ? "dodgerblue" : "gray"; }).ofObject()),
       $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
         { toArrow: "standard", strokeWidth: 0, fill: "gray" }),
       $(go.Panel, "Auto",  // the link label, normally not visible
         { visible: false, name: "LABEL", segmentIndex: 2, segmentFraction: 0.5 },
         new go.Binding("visible", "visible").makeTwoWay(),
         $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",  // the label shape
           { fill: "#F8F8F8", strokeWidth: 0 }),
         $(go.TextBlock, "Yes",  // the label
           {
             textAlign: "center",
             font: "10pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
             stroke: "#333333",
             editable: true
           },
           new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
       )
     );   
   this._diagram.layout.invalidateLayout();
 }


 load() {
    ...load data from backend...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a minor change from

```
constructor(private templatesService: TemplatesService,
   private router: Router,
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private projectsService: ProjectsService) { this.initDiagram(); }

ngOnInit() {
   // Get data
   this.load();
   setTimeout(() => { this.load(); });

 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   // We have data page is loaded => show graph
   this._diagram.div = this._diagramRef.nativeElement;

   this.scaleDiagramDivToHeightOf(window, -50);
   if (this.route.data['value']['label'] === 'design' ||
       this.route.data['value']['label'] === 'design-proto') {
     this.initDiagramDesign();
     this.initPalette();
   }


   this._diagram.requestUpdate();


 }
```

to

```
constructor(private templatesService: TemplatesService,
   private router: Router,
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private projectsService: ProjectsService) { this.initDiagram(); }

ngOnInit() {

 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   // We have data page is loaded => show graph
   this._diagram.div = this._diagramRef.nativeElement;

   this.scaleDiagramDivToHeightOf(window, -50);
   if (this.route.data['value']['label'] === 'design' ||
       this.route.data['value']['label'] === 'design-proto') {
     this.initDiagramDesign();
     this.initPalette();
   }


   this.load();
 }
```